# In Linq, how do you query based on a child record?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, linq-to-entities

I have a simple parent/child structure which stores a history of messages sent users.  I have generated a dbContext and linked all entites (using EF Core Power Tools).

So how can I actually get all notifications for a certain UserID when the UserIDs are in a child table (called PushNotificationReceipients)?

[image]

I thought I could do something like this but it fails with an error:

```
    var recipient = new PushNotificationRecipient();
    recipient.UserId = userId;
    var results = _dbContext.PushNotifications
        .Include(t => t.PushNotificationContents)
        .Where(t => t.PushNotificationRecipients.Contains(recipient))
        .ToList();
```

..but this gives the error

> The LINQ expression could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable()

..and client evaluation will be too slow.

Is there any way to do this in Linq or do I need to pass in the SQL directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two main problems with your the expression in your `Where`:

1. As the exception message tells you, that expression cannot be translated to SQL.
2. Even if it could be translated to SQL, `.Contains()` would return false nonetheless. That's because the new `PushNotificationRecipient` object that you created is not the same one in the collection. Just because it has the same id doesn't make the two objects equal.

Try something like the following:

```
var results = _dbContext.PushNotifications
    .Include(t => t.PushNotificationContents)
    .Where(t => t.PushNotificationRecipients.Any(r => r.UserId == userId))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: I was trying to use PushNotificationRecipients.Where()  but that isn't valid syntax for some reason.

Comment: @NickG If you want to use `Where`, you'd need `.Where(t => t.PushNotificationRecipients.Where(r => r.UserId == userId).Any())`. The above version is more readable though.

Comment: Ah yes I see now. Where() requires a boolean result so Any() is needed instead of a nested Where() (which would not result in a bool). Thanks very much!

Comment: Exactly. `Where()` would need to be followed by either `.Any()` or `.FirstOrDefault() != null`, which is an even longer version ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use ThenInclude, it's used for loading related data

```
var recipient = new PushNotificationRecipient();
recipient.UserId = userId;
var results = _dbContext.PushNotifications
 .Include(t => t.PushNotificationContents)
 .ThenInclude(t => t.PushNotificationRecipients)
 .Where(notification => notification.<your condition>)
 .ToList();
```